Fourier Optics of lenses and free space translations in terms of wave vectors
In Fourier Optics, the electric field may be described by a function $g(x,y)$ describing the field in the transverse plane at some $z$-location (propagation axis). From there, several transformations are applied to $g$ to obtain the output field at some other $z'>z$.
Equivalently, to $g$ as defined above, it should be possible to describe all of optics using wave vectors instead, by functions for the form $f(k_x, k_y)$, where $k_x$ and $k_y$ are the wave vector components corresponding to the spatial dimensions $x$ and $y$. If I understand it correctly, $f$ should be the ("$\vec{r}$ to $\vec{k}$") fourier transform of $g$.
Then, how does this affect the transfer functions of optical instruments? More specifically, I am now interested in the transfer functions of free space and a simple thin lens "in terms of wave vectors".
For example, in terms of $x$ and $y$, a translation in free space of the field described by $g$ by a distance $Z$ is given by the transform (see MIT OCW):
$$ \tilde{g}(x', y') = \int dx dy\ g(x,y) \exp\left(i\pi\frac{(x'-x)^2}{\lambda Z}\right) \exp\left(i\pi\frac{(y'-y)^2}{\lambda Z}\right) $$
Similarly, a lens is described by a phase factor (same Ref.):
$$ \tilde{g}(x,y) = g(x,y) \exp\left(-i\pi\frac{x^2}{\lambda f}\right) \exp\left(-i\pi\frac{y^2}{\lambda f}\right) $$
How do these transforms translate to wave vector descriptions of the electric field? That is, what do the above equations look like for $f$?

Far field propagation realizes the Fourier transform in the transformed coordinates $2\pi x'/\lambda z$ where $z$ is your propagation distance (replace $z \rightarrow f$ when you are in the focal plane). You can introduce the transversal wave-vector components through the angles between your optical axis and the point $(x',y')$ in the image domain. This is straightforward from the formulation you have. Basically, at this point, it is just a substitution. You may also solve the problem by propagating the angular spectrum $\tilde{g}(k_x,k_y)$ using the Fresnel-Kernel instead.

Careful, your second integral is not the Fourier transform! Check your integration variables and the plane waves!

@zimmervi Fixed it, the lens itself is just a phase factor. However, I'm not sure I understand you first answer...

What I want to say is no more than you already have everything there to just change the variables to transversal wavevector components, just check the exponentials and the definition of $k_x, k_y$. Then you have the propagation in terms of $k_x, k_y$ which should be equivalent to the convolution of your aperture function with the Fresnel-Kernel. If you introduce the far-field approximation, this convolution reduces to the Fourier transform of your aperture function in the scaled/transformed coordinates that I gave above. Fully expand your integral and you will be able to see it.

Alternatively, you can compute the angular spectrum $\tilde{g}(k_x, k_y) = \mathcal{F}\lbrace g(x,y) \rbrace$ of your input field and just propagate this, then do the inverse Fourier transform in the image plane to get back your original field. The coordinates stay the same. The angular spectrum propagates as $\tilde{g}(k_x, k_y; z) = \exp{(iwz)}\tilde{g}(k_x, k_y; 0)$ where $w = \sqrt{k^2-k_x^2-k_y^2}$.

You just need to use your Fourier theorems. The Fourier transform of the product of two functions is the convolution of their spectra. Likewise, the Fourier transform of the convolution of two functions is the product of their spectra.
For the lens you have a transmission function $t(x,y)$ that is multiplied with the input function to give the output
$$ g(x,y) = f(x,y)t(x,y) . $$
In the Fourier domain you'll get convolution of the input angular spectra $F(k_x,k_y)$ with the Fourier transform of the transmission function of the lens
$$ G(k_x,k_y) = \int F(p,q)T(k_x-p,k_y-q)\ dpdq , $$
where
$$ T(k_x,k_y) = \mathcal{F}\{t(x,y)\} . $$
For free space, the propagation process can be given by the Fresnel integral, which can be written as a convolution of the input function by the Fresnel kernel
$$ g(u,v) = \frac{-i\exp(ikz)}{\lambda z}\int f(x,y) \exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{\lambda z} [(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2]\right) , $$
which therefore acts like an impulse response. In the Fourier domain the input angular spectrum in multiplied by the Fourier transform of the Fresnel kernel (the transfer function)
$$ G(k_x,k_y) = F(k_x,k_y)\exp\left[ikz-\frac{i(k_x^2+k_y^2)}{2k}\right] , $$
which is in the form of a quadratic phase factor.

I think I understand it now, but some more math would also be appreciated

Math provided as requested
